# Filtering in joins

Tags: sql, join, filter

I have two tables.

Table 1

```
 ----RID---Name-----
      1     Process1
      2     Process2
```

Table 2

```
  -----RID------URID-----Status-----
       1         1        0
       1         2        1
       1         3        3
       2         4        0
```

I want to count all errors( status >1), all success(status < 2) in Table2 for each Name in Table1. Like this:

```
 -----RID----Success------Errors---
       1        2            1
       2        1            0
```

Here is the query I am trying to use, but doesn't work...Thought it would be smart to filter already in the join....What I am doing wrong here ?

```
 select distinct T1.[Name]
 ,count(T2.URID) as Error
 ,count(T3.URID) as Success
 FROM [dbo].[Table 1] T1
 left join [dbo].[Table 2] T2
 on T2.RID = T1.RID and T2.Status > 1
 left join [dbo].[Table 2] T3
 on T3.RID = T1.RID and T3.Status < 2
 group by RID
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: there isnot any need to join the tables is it?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this like below aswell,

```
 SELECT * INTO #T FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN T.[STATUS]>1 THEN COUNT(T.[STATUS]) ELSE 0 END [ERROR],
 CASE WHEN T.[STATUS]<2 THEN COUNT(T.[STATUS]) ELSE 0 END [SUCCESS],
 T2.NAME FROM TEST1 T2 INNER JOIN TEST2 T ON T.RID=T2.RID
 GROUP BY T.[STATUS],T2.[NAME]) T


 SELECT NAME,SUM([SUCCESS]) [SUCCESS],SUM(ERROR)[ERROR] FROM #T GROUP BY NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do aggregation :

```
select  t1.rid, t1.name,
        sum(case when status > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as error, 
        sum(case when status < 2 then 1 else 0 end) as success 
from table1 t1 inner join
     table2 t2
     on t2.rid = t1.rid
group by t1.rid, t1.name
```

However, the `DISTINCT` is not needed here if you have a `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select T1.[Name],
       sum(case when t2.status > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as errors,
       sum(case when t2.status < 2 then 1 else 0 end) as success
from [dbo].[Table 1] T1 left join
     [dbo].[Table 2] T2
     on T2.RID = T1.RID
group by T1.RID, T1.[Name];
```

It is also important to aggregate by the column being used to define each row `T1.Name`.  I'm not sure if `T1.RID` is needed in the `group by`, but you have it in your version.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
create table ns_999(col1 number,col2 number,col3 number);

 insert into ns_999 values( 1,1,0);
 insert into ns_999 values(1,2 ,1);
 insert into ns_999 values(1,3,3);
  insert into ns_999 values(2,4,0);
  SELECT * FROM ns_999;

  select col1,
       sum(case when col3>1 then 1 else 0 end ) as errors, 
       sum(case when col3<2 then 1 else 0 end) as sucess
from ns_999 
group by col1;
```

sample output:

```
 RID FALIURE SUCCESS 
    1      1       2
    2      0       1
```